# не могу разобраться в чем ошибка. Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

нужно было сделать обычный калькулятор на Python с использованием PyQt5. Выдает ошибку, помогите пожалуйста.
вот код:

```html
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton


class Calculator(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        grid = Q6ridLayout()
        self.setlayout(grid)

    btn_names = ['Cls', 'Bck', '', 'Close',
                 '7', '8', '9', '/',
                 '4', '5', '6', '*',
                 '1', '2', '3', '-',
                 '0', '.', '=', '+' ]

    positions = [(i, j) for i in range(5) for j in range(4)]

    for name, pos in zip(btn_names, positions);
        if name == "":
            continue
        button = QPushButton(name)
        grid.addWidget(button, *pos)
    self.move(300, 150)
    self.setWindowTitle("Calculator")
    self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cals = Calculator()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PyQt5.

Comment: Какую ошибку? .

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял вы об этой ошибке - line 22
for name, pos in zip(btn_names, positions);
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Вы использовали точку с запятой ; вместо двоеточия : в 22 строке кода.
Также в вашем коде есть еще одна ошибка. В строке 10 вы написали Q6ridLayout() вместо QGridLayout()

Вот полный код с исправлениями:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QGridLayout


class Calculator(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        btn_names = ['Cls', 'Bck', '', 'Close',
                     '7', '8', '9', '/',
                     '4', '5', '6', '*',
                     '1', '2', '3', '-',
                     '0', '.', '=', '+']

        positions = [(i, j) for i in range(5) for j in range(4)]

        for name, pos in zip(btn_names, positions):
            if name == "":
                continue
            button = QPushButton(name)
            grid.addWidget(button, *pos)
        self.move(300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calculator")
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cals = Calculator()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо) еще нет модуля pyqt5, хотя библиотека установлена